# How to move the mouse cursor automatically smooth from a random place to a specific place in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make the mouse cursor automatically move from a random place to a specific place on my unity game screen.

I'm using Mouse.current.WarpCursorPosition, and Vector3.MoveTowards for what i want to make.

But it doesn't work at all.

Here's my code.

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEditor;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class TestMousemove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject G;

    public float Speed;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            Mouse.current.WarpCursorPosition(transform.position = 
                Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, G.transform.position, Speed * Time.deltaTime));
        }
    }
}
```

https://youtu.be/VzEnDi7wmnc

and this is how it works.

I want to make it move smoothly like the cursor follows the location.

Is there anyone knows about the question, please answer here.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it's quite strange to provide an argument and assign a value at the same time, but maybe I don't know about something. Nevertheless, it seems your expression `transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, G.transform.position, Speed * Time.deltaTime)` always produce the same result, hence, your mouse always warps to the same position.

When I changed it to:

```
transform.position =
            Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, G.transform.position, Speed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) Mouse.current.WarpCursorPosition(
            Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, G.transform.position, Speed * Time.deltaTime));
```

it seems to work, but when I move the mouse, it instantly warps to the position of transform.position + Speed * Time.delta time.

My solution is to replace transform.position with your current mouse position, so the `current` argument of `MoveTowards` method will be the actual mouse position, not position of the object this script is attached to:

```
Mouse.current.WarpCursorPosition(
            Vector2.MoveTowards(Mouse.current.position.ReadValue(), G.transform.position, Speed * Time.deltaTime));
```

Comment: It works at least, also I changed GetKeyDown to GetKey. By the way there's a problem that I found. It doesn't go back (It means doesn't go to the right or down side if it is already up and left.) It's hard to describe so I got a video to show you what the problem is. https://youtu.be/TdIfeRpb80A

Comment: No idea why would that happen, probably you need to tweak your arguments to get desired effect. Can't say much without the code. You could try logging positions you supply your method with to get an idea. If you continue to have a problem with that, you could ask another question, as smooth movement is already covered.

Comment: I just tested on the build version and it totally works! There's some glitch on the editor version.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple problems here:

- You are not fully committed to the new input system, which the editor should warn you about. You're still using the Input class.
- The Mouse position is in screenspace while you attempt to use transforms from worldspace. Unless you did a ton of experimenting and fine tuning this will result in odd behavior.
- Your "Mouse movement code" is only active for one frame, namely the one where you press the `A` button. It's never going to be a smooth animation with only one frame.

Here's some code that should do what you want:

```sharp
    [SerializeField] Vector2 target;
    [SerializeField] float speed = 100;

    bool moving;
    Vector2 position;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Mouse.current.rightButton.isPressed)
        {
            position = Mouse.current.position.ReadValue();
            moving = true;
        }
        if (moving)
        {
            position = Vector2.MoveTowards(position, target, Time.deltaTime * speed);
            Mouse.current.WarpCursorPosition(position);
            moving = Vector2.Distance(position, target) > 0.1f;
        }
    }
```

The mouse will start to move when you press the right mouse button. It will move at a speed of 100 pixels per second until it reaches the specified target notated in pixel units.

**Note** It might glitch in the editor, but will work guaranteed in the build. If you execute in windowed mode and the coordinate is off screen the mouse will get stuck at the edge of your physical screen. Also keep in mind that the user is able to fight the adjustment.

Comment: It actually works just like another answer I got, but still can't solve one problem. I can't make it move to right side and down side. For example, if the target is placed on the right side of the cursor, the cursor doesn't move. Now I have to find out how to solve it.

Comment: @UnityGameDeveloper3877 As I said, it can act weird in the editor. In my tests the code could reach any point on the screen. Not quite sure what to make of your issue.

Comment: You are right. I didn't understand what is the glitch in the editor and I just thought it doesn't work. When I play it on my build version it totally worked.

Comment: @UnityGameDeveloper3877 have in mind that in the editor the mouse position is still in screenspace => it might happen that if you play in windowed (in contrary to maximized) GameView mode then Unity might add some clamping so you can only reach the gameView screen size and not your actual display